# Configuring colors/background colors CSS

Tags: html, css

While designing/changing the page layout, I have a coloring for each of div/class elements as needed. That enables me to clearly see the structure of the layout.

While testing/presenting the page layout with the actual content, I have a different coloring scheme.

I need to switch between the two often. How can I accomplish this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing you could **add a class** to your `html` or `body` tag

**e.g.** `<html class="testingMode">`

and then in your **stylesheet** you could have **overrides to your other styles**

**e.g.**

```
/*Normal/Live mode*/
.divClass {
    background: none;
}

/*Testing mode*/
.testingMode .divClass {
    background: green;
}
```

Before you go live you can remove the class of `testingMode` from your `html` tag and those overriding styles will not be applied.

Comment: Being not an expert, I am not in a position to mark answer as right/wrong. However I get the idea to solve my problem. Thx

Comment: i suggest marking the answer that you ended up using as the right answer

Answer (score 3):

Use two CSS files. Each with the same classes but different colour values etc. Have a batch file to swap the two. You could put together a fancier skinning approach using your hosts file and some magic in your web-server but that may well be overkill for your needs.

Comment: I thought about that (though first I need to investigate how to use the batch file to swap). But, In that case, I need to sync the two css files every time I make a change to either one of them. I was hoping if there was some way using only single CSS file. But I guess not?? Thx for the super quick response

Comment: You can import other stylesheets at the top of your stylesheet, so it may be possible to define some "macros" for your colour values and then use them in your main stylesheet. You'd just need to swap the include then (which only includes colours and nothing else of interest).

Comment: ah. Let me try that. Thanks for tips